# Force error log file in current directory

Tags: php, apache, logging, error-handling

i have a developement dir on my server but i dont have root access so i cant change which php ini file loads.   I ask my host if they would set things up so that i could have a custom php ini file but they dont allow that.

I am always having to go all the way back to the public dir to check the error log file during development.  I would like to force the dev folder to create its own error log file.  Is there a way to do this without root access.  I just want to be able to check errors in the dev dir because its faster to check them.

I have already added a php.ini file to my dev dir. And inside that php ini file i have the error log location code

```
  ;just for testing
  error_reporting = E_ALL

  error_log = '/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx_dev/error_log'
```

but its probably not doing anything as they dont allow those.  Can i do this with htaccess?  or is there another way to do this for a local error log?

I am on a linux apache machine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the .htaccess file...

## enable PHP error logging

php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xx_dev/error_log

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to change system default behavior.

```php
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    // do something
}

set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set error_log file in .htaccess, for example

```
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
```

This file should be writable for apache process user (www-data, apache - see apache config).

Comment: not working on windows  10, in WAMP enviornment